# Localization in Android - language specific folders

Tags: android, android-resources

I had a simple question. I was just going through the code of an app and just saw that some resources which were setting Boolean values, used for settings some conditions based on language and region. The file was replicated in the different language specific values folder. I saw that there were different folders named values-de-rDE and values-de. This was for German. Why the different folders for German? Which resource file would be picked up for German? Different folders were specified for some other languages too. Like for French I had values-fr and values-fr-rFR.

Could some one please explain what the difference between the two folders is? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `values-fr` and `values-fr-rFR` is that the first is filtering on the language only, while the second is filtering on the country. `fr-rFR` means French in France. You would have `values-fr-rCA` for French in Canada, for example.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for the reply. I just checked a couple of phones. It did prove your point where I had a language called French(Canada) and French(France) but I also see on some other phone just French listed. Also only German was listed in both phones that I checked. So my question would be, do we need to define boolean values separately in values-fr(to take into account phones which listed only french as a language) and boolean values in values-fr-rFR and values-fr-rCA (to take into account phones with frFR and frCA listed as separate languages)?

Comment: If you define just `values-fr`, every phone in french will fall back in it. Android choose the most precise folder it finds. If you don't give it a `values-frFR`, it will fall back to `values-fr`. If you don't give it a `values-fr` neither, `values`. If you don't give it a `values`, well… :-)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `values-de-rDE` and `values-de` is that the first is referring to the **country and language**, while the other only requires the **language**.

What region is chosen can be determined in System Settings. *German (Germany)* is `values-de-rDE` while *German (Switzerland)* is `values-de-rCH`, but both are `values-de`.

If the system is set to *German (Germany)*, it will first read all values from `values-de-rDE`, then the missing values from `values-de`, and finally from the default `values`.

This is useful for when `values` contains American English, and `values-en-rGB` can provide only the strings that are different (i.e. colo*u*r, flavo*u*r, customi*s*e).

Answer (score 0):

These resource folders are used to custom your application depending on your language. The most common use of these folder is to have text translated to different languages, but they could be used to apply some restrictions country-based. It is up to the developer to define these folder and these translations. Or maybe you could add diferent icons aswell (an icon with a text that you want to change depending on the language of the device)

Usually if you are going to define a boolean value which is not country/language dependant you  would put it only in your  main res folder (values.xml).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) you may find more information.

Hope you find this information useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the usage of resource folders and how the different language settings are applied. If I was not clear in my question earlier, I just wanted to understand the difference between the values-de-rDE and values-de. I believe both represent German but what is the difference?